# private:void _cdecl tensorflow::GraphDef::InternalSwap(class tensorflow::GraphDef *)"

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-2015

I have built tensorflow.lib and tensorflow.dll successfully in visual studio 2015,but I'm trying to use those two files I got this error LNK 2001 private:void  _cdecl tensorflow::GraphDef::InternalSwap(class tensorflow::GraphDef *)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the root cause of this issue.
But below is the workaround solution for my case.
I added `GraphDef::InternalSwap()` function manually in my code.

```
namespace tensorflow {
    void GraphDef::InternalSwap(GraphDef* other) {
        using std::swap;
        CastToBase(&node_)->InternalSwap(CastToBase(&other->node_));
        swap(library_, other->library_);
        swap(versions_, other->versions_);
        swap(version_, other->version_);
        _internal_metadata_.Swap(&other->_internal_metadata_);
    }
}
```